# Batch Script to list the root folder and then all files inside it greater than a specified size

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a script where I have to list all the folders inside a folder with the following logic:

Say folder A, B, C are inside folder F
and A, B and C contain subfolders and files.

I have to write a script that would show the Folder A, B , C as header and then lists the files above a specified size inside them(including subfolders)... if possible with their modified date.

I have prepared a skeleton.

> @echo off & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
> pushd C:\F
>
> for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/b/a:d') do (

```
echo %%a >>C:\F\list.txt
echo "-----------------------------------------------">>C:\F\list.txt
pushd %%a 
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('dir/b/s') do (
    echo %%i >>C:\F\list.txt
    if %%~Za gtr 10000 echo %%i is %%~Za >>C:\F\list.txt
    ))
```

The the desired output is:

### Directory A

file1 size1 date1

file2 size2 date2

### Directory B

file3 size3 date3

file4 size4 date4

### Directory C

file5 size5 date5

file6 size6 date6

---date field is not mandatory but better if included.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general idea for the code. It basically searches through each directory and sub directory, and finds all the files of a specified type. Then the program finds each unique file directory and search for files greater than the specified size to output in the format you requested. Note: There is a lot of "extra" included in the code for troubleshooting purposes. Feel free to remove the unnecessary text files as you please. =]

```
@echo off & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion pushd C:\F

::sets size limit
SET sizelimit=10000

::searches for all files in directories and subdirectories and outputs to files.txt
dir /b/s >> files.txt

::finds all .zip files in files.txt
type files.txt | findstr /E .zip > myfile1.txt

::finds all .zip file locations and unique file locations
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in (myfile1.txt) do @echo %%~dpa >>filelocations.txt
FOR /F "delims==" %%L in (filelocations.txt) do find "%%L" unique.txt>nul || echo %%L>>unique.txt

::Loops through each unique location, finds all the .zip files and checks if they are larger
:: than the specified file size, then outputs the results to output.txt
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (unique.txt) do (
echo %%a >>output.txt
findstr "%%a" myfile1.txt >temp.txt
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (temp.txt) do (
if %%~za gtr %sizelimit% echo %%~nxa %%~za %%~ta >>output.txt
)
)

end local

::Cleans up extra files (which are generated for troubleshooting purposes)
del files.txt myfile1.txt filelocations.txt unique.txt temp.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeff k. This was helpful. However, in the Unique.txt all the sub-folders will be considered as unique file location. Consequently they will be printed with  "echo %%a >>output.txt". My need is to print only the folders inside folder "F" as header i.e. A,B,C and list down the files inside each folder(including sub-folders) based on their size. Could you please help this?

Comment: @user1697214 The for loop for unique.txt: `FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (unique.txt) do (echo %%a >>output.txt` should print each subfolder, then proceed to find all of the files under that subfolder, then print subfolder2 and print all of the files under subfolder2, etc. You could also add spaces under the `echo %%a >>output.txt` line to emphasize the header format

Answer (score 0):

In answer to [your question HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583313/batch-script-to-list-the-root-folder-and-then-all-files-inside-it-greater-than-a/12592546#comment17097074_12592546).

Well, you could pipe the output to `sort`, but there are at least three problems with that.

The first problem is that when you just tack it to the end, it only sort's one line at a time. Meaning it doesn't sort at all.  To fix that, you can put the entire `for` command inside a block `()` then pipe the output of the block to `sort`, which causes other problems, though I'm confident that it's possible to solve these issues.

The second problem with that is that it sort's the date alphabetically, starting with the month. This means that all Januaries `1/dd/yyyy` will come first, then all Octobers `10/dd/yyyy` meaning that you get all the years mixed together, AND it's sorted January, October, November, December, Febuary, March, etc.

You could sort by size by using `sort`'s `/+col` command, but you'll be comparing `size[tab]filename` meaning `2[tab]hello` comes AFTER `1000[tab]hello`. (Type `sort /?`<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to learn more about sort.)

What I reccomend is that use use `dir`'s ability to sort like so:

```
:: Sort by name
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b /o:n ') do @if %%~za gtr %sizelimit% echo %%~ta%tab%%%~za%tab%%%~nxa

:: Sort by size
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b /o:s ') do @if %%~za gtr %sizelimit% echo %%~ta%tab%%%~za%tab%%%~nxa

:: Sort by date
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b /o:d ') do @if %%~za gtr %sizelimit% echo %%~ta%tab%%%~za%tab%%%~nxa
```

There are other options for the `/o:` order command. Type `dir /?`<kbd>ENTER</kbd> at the command prompt for more information on how `dir` works.

Comment: Thank you so much for enlightling my knowledge base. I want to sort by Size, therefore the ('dir /b /o:s ') option looks good for me. However, it doest not traverse into the sub folders and I have ('dir /b /s ') in my script. Therefore I tried using ('dir /b /s /o:s') but this doesnot sort the whole file list. What it does is that, it sorts the files in each directory only. Could it be possible to sort the whole list(files inside subfolders) ?

Comment: No, the only way to sort the entire directory tree is to read the entire tree into memory, or into a file, and then sort it that way.

Comment: @user1697214 - I realized you probably didn't get my message, so: "No, the only way to sort the entire directory tree is to read the entire tree into memory, or into a file, and then sort it that way"